# How do i reinstall and use the default kernel?

Tags: settings, kernel, default

^^ I installed xanmod and cant seem to get rid of it (it doesnt work with official nvidia drivers), i tried everything I knew to switch back to the default but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal :

```
sudo - i
```

Provide your password to become a root. 
Then type in terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

This will list all installed kernels.

To remove unwanted kernel type in terminal:

```
apt remove linux-image-number of the kernel you want to remove
```

Or eventually something like

```
apt remove 5.7.2-xanmod1
```

Or

```
apt remove linux-xanmod
```

This I think should work.

Then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

To update grub.

Additionally install grub customizer. Link: [how to install grub customizer](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

And select which kernel should be loaded as first.